# Eliminar texto de un campo para convertirlo a int en dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

estoy intentando limpiar una columna de un dataframe de pandas.
He intentado convertir un objeto de tipo object en int64:

```
df2['Pts'] = df2['Pts'].astype(int)
```

Pero no me deja porque hay cadena de texto en estos campos, todos son numéricos pero en algunos casos aparece así: 55[a] o 55[b]

He intentado eliminar esas cadenas de texto que aparecen al final de los números para poder convertirlo, pero no me es posible.

```
df2.replace(['[a]', '[b]'], ['', ''])
```

Alguien pude sugerirme alguna idea para que no aparezcan esas cadenas de texto dentro de mis valores int para poder operar con dichos datos.
Muchas gracias de antemano.
Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de muchas maneras diferentes. Te propongo varias:

**Con regex**

```py
import re

regex = re.compile(r'[^0-9]') # Eliminamos todo lo que no sean números
df['Pts'] = df['Pts'].replace(regex, '').astype(int)
```

**Con extract**

Nota: haciéndolo de esta forma sólo vas a tener la primera cadena de números que aparezcan de manera consecutiva

```py
df['Pts'] = df['Pts'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
```

**Con una lambda + `isdigit`**

```py
df['Pts'] = df['Pts'].map(lambda x: ''.join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()])).astype(int)
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias por la ayuda. Me ha servido para solucionar el problema. Un saludo